# DataGridComboBox Column is not displaying values from bound collection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid. One of its columns is a ComboBox column.

I want populate this ComboBox with only two choices. 'Cheque' or 'transfer'.

But the ComboBox remains empty and when I load the DataGrid, this column is empty.

**View**

```
     <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridsupplier" 
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Full Company Name" Binding="{Binding fullCompanyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
              <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Payment Method" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Method}"
                                      SelectedItemBinding="{Binding methodOfPayment}"/>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class SupplierViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public Context ctx = new Context();

    public SupplierViewModel()
    {
        Get();
        Method = new List<string> { "Transfer", "Cheque" };
    }

    private ObservableCollection<foodSupplier> collection;

    public ObservableCollection<foodSupplier> Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return collection;
        }
        set
        {
            collection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
        }
    }

    private IList<string> _method;

    public IList<string> Method
    {
        get
        {
            return _method;
        }
        set
        {
            _method = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Method");
        }
    }

    private void Get()
    {
        ctx.foodSuppliers.ToList().ForEach(supplier => ctx.foodSuppliers.Local.Add(supplier));
        Collection = ctx.foodSuppliers.Local;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public partial class foodSupplier
{
    public string fullCompanyName { get; set; }
    public string methodOfPayment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: methodOfPayment should of type `RecordValues` instead of `string`.

Comment: @Rohit Vats, I updated my code to do it another way. But still doesn't work.

Comment: What is foodSuppliers in you code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DataGridComboBoxColumn` or any other supported data grid columns are not part of visual tree of `datagrid` so they don't inherit the `DataContext` of `datagrid`. Since, they don't lie in visual tree so any try to get `DataContext` using RelativeSource won't work.

Solution - You can create a proxy element to bind the data context of window; use that proxy element to bind the ItemsSource of DataGridComboBoxColumn.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
       <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
   </Grid.Resources>
       <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"></ContentControl>
       <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridsupplier" 
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Full Company Name" Binding="{Binding fullCompanyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
              <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Payment Method" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Method, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}"
                                      SelectedItemBinding="{Binding methodOfPayment}"/>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> That's how the Datagrid works. You have a CellTemplate and a
>   CellEditingTemplate. The former is just a textblock, the latter is the
>   combobox. Same, with other Datagrid columns, you have to click the
>   cell to enter edit mode. In fact by default you have to select the
>   row, then the cell. Which I admit is a bit clucnky.

Excerpt taken from [WPF - DataGridComboBoxColumn Problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64f36ca4-bde9-4f32-8260-2b84e53bd8ca/wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn-problem?forum=wpf)

This is a bug and a good discussion can be found at [CodePlex](http://wpf.codeplex.com/workitem/8153).

If you want to see the combobox all the time, you need to make your own column template.
Template column is working just fine :

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Payment Method">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Method}" 
                             SelectedItemBinding="{Binding methodOfPayment}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
```